# How to set number of line to display in a List Portlet in Netsuite?

Tags: javascript, portlet, netsuite

How to set number of line to display in a List Portlet in Netsuite? For example display only 10 lines and press ">" to view next 10 list or scrolldown to view?

```
function displayEmailList(portlet, column) {

var col = portlet.addColumn('view','text', 'View', 'LEFT');
var col = portlet.addColumn('messagedate','date', 'Date', 'LEFT');
var col = portlet.addColumn('author_display','text', 'Author', 'LEFT');
var col = portlet.addColumn('recipient_display','text', 'Recipient', 'LEFT');
var col = portlet.addColumn('subject','text', 'Subject', 'LEFT');
var col = portlet.addColumn('hasattachment','text', 'Attachment', 'LEFT');

var returncols = new Array();
returncols[0] = new nlobjSearchColumn('view');
returncols[1] = new nlobjSearchColumn('messagedate');
returncols[2] = new nlobjSearchColumn('author');
returncols[3] = new nlobjSearchColumn('recipient');
returncols[4] = new nlobjSearchColumn('subject');
returncols[5] = new nlobjSearchColumn('hasattachment');
var results = nlapiSearchRecord('message', null, null, returncols);

portlet.setTitle("Email List :" );

for ( var i = 0; i < results.length; i++ ){
    portlet.addRow( results[i] )
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looping through the entire Array, initially just loop `i` from 0 through 9. Then, whenever the user clicks your `>` button, remove all the rows in the list, update the limits of your loop accordingly, and re-run the loop.

I'd recommend breaking the `addRow` for-loop out into its own function so that you can easily ask it to add a specific number of rows with a specific start.

Comment: This is a list Portlet and I don't think we can have Button(Previous, Next) on list Portlet. I just realise while trying the change you recommend. I guess I have to change the Portlet type to have custom format. Thank you erictgrubaugh